# Transition Text Position with CSS

Tags: css, css-transitions

I have a page with 4 equal images that each take up 25% of the page in seperate divs. On hover, an image overlay appears and then text transitions start as well, which all function properly.

The question is, how would I go about aligning my text in the center of each image (or div), and then create a transition where the text slides to another position? They're currently centered the way that I'd like, but I'm not sure where to add the transition...

I've found ways to transition the text in the manner that I want, but I cannot get it to center first. Any help would be much appreciated. JS Fiddle and code below.

JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/n39wkkb1/1/

**CSS:**

```
body {
    background: url('http://www.bootply.com/assets/example/bg_blueplane.jpg');
    height:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
div.bg {
    position:fixed;
    width:50%;
    height:50%
}
#nw {
    background-image: url('clevelandnight.jpg');
    background-size:cover;
}
#ne {
    top:0;
    left:50%;
    background-image: url('news1.jpg');
    background-size:cover;
}
#sw {
    top:50%;
    left:0;
    background-image: url('drinks1.jpg');
    background-size:cover;
}
#se {
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    background-image: url('clevelandday.jpg');
    background-size:cover;
}
.overlay {
    height:100%;
    text-align:center;
    -webkit-transition:opacity .4s ease-out, height .4s ease-out, background .4s ease-out;
    -moz-transition:opacity .4s ease-out, height .4s ease-out, background .4s ease-out;
    -o-transition:opacity .4s ease-out, height .4s ease-out, background .4s ease-out;
    -ms-transition:opacity .4s ease-out, height .4s ease-out, background .4s ease-out;
    transition:opacity .4s ease-out, height .4s ease-out, background .4s ease-out;
}
.bg:hover .overlay {
    background:rgba(0, 0, 0, .75);
    opacity: 1;
    height:100%;
}
.caption {
    font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed', sans-serif;
    font-weight:100;
    color:white;
    font-size:36pt;
    -webkit-transition:font-size .4s ease-out 1s, color .4s ease-out 1s;
    -moz-transition:font-size .4s ease-out 1s, color .4s ease-out 1s;
    -o-transition:font-size .4s ease-out 1s, color .4s ease-out 1s;
    transition:font-size .4s ease-out 1s, color .4s ease-out 1s;
}
.bg:hover .caption {
    color:#7D7D7D;
    font-size:72px;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans+Condensed:300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <title>Craig Does Cleveland</title>
    <link href='stylesheet2.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id='nw' class='bg'>
      <div class='overlay'>
          <span class='caption'>Night Life</span>
      </div>

    </div>
    <div id='ne' class='bg'>
      <div class='overlay'>
        <span class='caption'>News</span>
      </div>
    </div>
        <div id='sw' class='bg'>
      <div class='overlay'>
        <span class='caption'>Food & Drink</span>
      </div>
    </div>
        <div id='se' class='bg'>
      <div class='overlay'>
        <span class='caption'>Events</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sorry, I updated my JS Fiddle a moment ago. After the text transitions size and color, I would like it to transition positions

Comment: you can simply use margin property for this purpose http://jsfiddle.net/hbirjand/n39wkkb1/5/

Comment: OK, where do you want to transition the text to?

Comment: Is this what you mean: http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/n39wkkb1/3/ ?

Comment: If I could transition it to the left so it goes from top center to top left that would be ideal (any position will do, though, because I can go in and edit as necessary once I see the solution)

Comment: Like this? http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/n39wkkb1/7/

Comment: @web-tiki That's perfect! Can you tell me what exactly was changed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add the transition on the margin-right property of `.caption` :

```
.caption {
    font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed', sans-serif;
    font-weight:100;
    color:white;
    font-size:36pt;
    -webkit-transition:font-size .4s ease-out 1s, color .4s ease-out 1s, margin-right .4s ease-out 1.4s;
    -moz-transition:font-size .4s ease-out 1s, color .4s ease-out 1s, margin-right .4s ease-out 1.4s;
    -o-transition:font-size .4s ease-out 1s, color .4s ease-out 1s, margin-right .4s ease-out 1.4s;
    transition:font-size .4s ease-out 1s, color .4s ease-out 1s, margin-right .4s ease-out 1.4s;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/n39wkkb1/7/)**

Comment: +1 and also addition of the `margin-right` on `hover` of `bg`.

Comment: Thank you so much for this, this is awesome it transitions to `text-left` in a very feasible way. I am trying to transition to `text-right` however I am overflowing, may you please see the topic I created - http://stackoverflow.com/q/38622227/1828637