# Transition centered text to left / right edges without overflowing

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I was able to transition `text-align` from `center` to `left`. With this code, if you run it, then hover over, you'll see the top one goes to the left. However the bottom overflows on the `right`; how can I figure out how to make the transition to `right` not overflow?

Note: This is a demo of my real application, which has strings/elements of unknown/variable width, from 1 to anything to fill a single line (no wrapping).

```css
.header {
  position: fixed;
  width: 70%;
  background-color: springgreen;
}
.title {
  text-align: center;
}
.menu {
  text-align: center;
}
.trans-left {
  transition: margin-right 1s;
}
.trans-right {
  transition: margin-left 1s;
}
.header:hover .trans-left {
  margin-right: 100%;
}
.header:hover .trans-right {
  margin-left: 100%;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class='header'>
    <div class='title'>
      <span class='trans-left'>This one goes left</span>
    </div>
    <div class='menu'>
      <span class='trans-right'>This one goes right</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're aligning the text elements like this:

```
margin-left: 100%;
margin-right: 100%;
```

This positions each element – *from the starting point of the box* – to the left and right edges.

Hence, the *left edge* of the left-moving box will align with the left edge of the container.

And the *left edge* of the right-moving box will align with the right edge of the container. This causes the rest of this box to overflow.

Try this instead:

```
margin-right: 90%; /* adjust as needed */
```

---

***Edit based on revised question***

Here is an alternative solution that works regardless of content width.

```css
.header {
  position: fixed;
  width: 70%;
  background-color: springgreen;
}
.title, .menu {
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
}
.trans-left {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  transition: 1s;
}
.trans-right {
  position: absolute;
  right: 50%;
  transform: translateX(50%);
  transition: 1s;
}
.header:hover .trans-left {
  left: 0;
  transform: translateX(0);
  transition: 1s;
}
.header:hover .trans-right {
  right: 0;
  transform: translateX(0);
  transition: 1s;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <div class="title">
    <span class="trans-left">This one goes left</span>
  </div>
  <div class="menu">
    <span class="trans-right">This one goes right</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

More details: *[Element will not stay centered, especially when re-sizing screen](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36817249/3597276)*

Comment: Hi Michael, yes if I reduce the percentage it will work, however the width is not known, this is a small example of what I am applying this to, which is hundereds, and they are all different widths. So 70% will work for a 20+ character string, but it wont work for 1 character string. :(

Comment: Wow thanks very much @Micahel I will play with it, this new method seems much better! It works for more then just text. Thank you!

Comment: Your way is so good! It respects the transition time 100% thank you so much! The `margin-right` method would push it to 100% but the transition time was not respected, as the 100% be overflow. Wow thank you!